# Ejb3 CMT not commiting foreign key constraint

Tags: transactions, foreign-keys, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to do a transaction that:

1. creates a Client
2. creates an Address with foreign key to Client table
3. updates a Client's composed foreign key to Address table

**PROBLEM:**

1. when running testMethod() i get a  **java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException**
   regarding ADDRESSES's constraint
2. if i change the code and create client in one transaction and then create the address and update the client field on another transaction, everything works fine
3. if i change the code and create the client and the address in one transaction and update the client field on another transaction, everything works fine aswell
4. **if i use nativequeries instead of persist and merge method from the EntityManager, everything works ok**

   ```
   @Stateless
   public class Test implements TestLocal {

   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "testPU")
   private EntityManager em;

   @Override
   public void testMethod(Client client, Address address, boolean mainAddress) {
     client.setIdcliente(new Long(110));
     em.persist(client);

     address.setAddressPK(new AddressPK(new Long(120), client.getIdcliente()));
     em.persist(address);

     if (mainAddress) {
       client.setMainAddress(address);
       em.merge(client);
     }
   }
   ```

My models:

CLIENTS:
 - IDCLIENTE pk
 - NMORADAPRI nullable

FOREIGN KEY (IDCLIENTE, NMORADAPRI) REFERENCES ADDRESSES (IDCLIENTE, IDMORADA)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENTS")
public class Client implements Serializable {

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "IDCLIENTE")
private Long idcliente;

@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDCLIENTE",  referencedColumnName = "IDCLIENTE", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "NMORADAPRI", referencedColumnName = "IDMORADA")})
@OneToOne(optional = false)
private Address main_address;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "client")
private Collection<Address> addressesCollection;
```

ADDRESSES:
 - IDMORADA  pk
 - IDCLIENTE pk

FOREIGN KEY (IDCLIENTE) REFERENCES CLIENTS (IDCLIENTE)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESSES")
public class Address implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
protected AddressPK addressPK;

@JoinColumn(name = "IDCLIENTE", referencedColumnName = "IDCLIENTE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Client client;
```

compose key

```
@Embeddable
public class AddressPK implements Serializable {

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "IDMORADA")
private long idmorada;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "IDCLIENTE")
private long idcliente;
```